# Cannot set property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, properties

My script is running well but at the end I get an error message Error during script execution.

```
Cannot set property 'status' of undefined.
```

Does anybody have a clue what I am doing wrong here?

```
const fs = require("fs-promise");
const axios = require("axios");
const jsonxml = require("jsonxml");
const tmp = require("tmp");

module.exports = {
  mpGetChecklist: async function (mpurl, bearer, systemGetChecklistMethod, systemGetChecklistId, systemGetChecklistDatasetName) {
    var getChecklist = {
      method: systemGetChecklistMethod,
      url: mpurl + "/connector/system/getChecklist?id=" + systemGetChecklistId,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + bearer,
      },
    };

    let tmpPath = tmp.fileSync({ postfix: ".xml" });
    let result;
    await axios(getChecklist)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        let xmlOptions = { header: true, root: "JSON", indent: true };
        let xmlString = jsonxml(response.data, xmlOptions);
        try {
          fs.writeFileSync(tmpPath.name, xmlString);
          result = { status: "succes", xmlPath: tmpPath.name, datasetName: systemGetChecklistDatasetName };
        } catch (error) {
          result = { status: "error", msg: error };
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    return result;
  },
};
```

Comment: I don't see anything trying to set the `status` property. Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` with `then()` syntax!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing means you are trying to set a property on an object that hasn't been defined yet.

In your code, if neither the `try` nor the `catch` inside `.then()` run, the variable `result` remains undefined. When you try to return it, you get an error.

Here's a simplified fix:

1. Set a default value for `result` at the beginning.
2. If the `axios` request fails, update the `result` inside the `catch`.

```js
let result = { status: "unknown" }; //<--- Here, initialize the value

await axios(getChecklist)
  .then(function (response) {
    // ...your logic within success
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    result = { status: "error", msg: error.message };
  });

return result;
```